# How to navigate in multileveled modal dialog window with the same code using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I have modal dialog window in images block on OPENCART site that has folder-looking elements with elements, and clicking one folder-element, I go inside this folder-element and there is another folder-element in it, which I need to click too.
I'm trying to write code in selenium/python to go through all those folder-elements, but html-path of inner folder-element is the same as previous folder-element's html-path.
The elems' tree look like this:
modal_dialog = id="filemanager"
inside of modal dialog theres elements: [folder1, folder2, folder3, folder4, folder5, folder6, *images]
Inside folder3 there's another level - [folder3-1, folder3-2]
and inside folder3-2 there's elements i need.

Can someone help me? I spent many days, resolving this, but still find resolution.

I used find_elements(By.XPATH...) and index to make selenium click the third folder-element of outerlevel like this:

```py
modal_dialog = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="text-center"]//a[@class="directory"]//i[@class="fa fa-folder fa-5x"]')
folder3 = modal_dialog[2]
folder3.click()
```

Folder3-2 has the same htmlpath as outer folders and inner folders.

I used fullXPATH: `/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a/i`
but the same fullXPATH has folder2.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the elements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okey,  i resolved the problem. I just added time.sleep(1), because XPath was dynamic